# How to get next 2 or 3 characters after specific word

Tags: java, android, bash

I have many lines like this:

```
    <mixer name="Adif2 Input Volume" value0="96" value1="96" />
    <mixer name="Adif2 Input Switch" value0="1" value1="1" />
    <mixer name="Voice Input Volume" value0="101" value1="96" />
    <mixer name="Voice Input Switch" value0="1" value1="1" />
    <mixer name="Ext Input Volume" value0="96" value1="96" />`
```

I would like to get numbers after value0=" text (numbers in value0 can be from 0 to 127), but only from Voice Input Volume and Voice Input Switch lines for example. How can i do this in Java?

Comment: I can also use bash command, so maybe it's the easiest way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `indexOf(..)`
For example:

```
int b = str.indexOf("value0=\"") + "value0=\"".length();
int e = str.indexOf("\"",b);
String number = str.substring(b,e);
```

Comment: It was the easiest way to do this :)

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the xml (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/readingXML.html)

or use regex with a capturing group (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)